# Why Edge restore scroll if doesn't have the scrollRestoration feature?

Tags: javascript, scroll, microsoft-edge

I am using Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 (I also tried in other PCs) it does the scroll restoration and checking if is compatible with the feature `'scrollRestoration' in history` it tells it's not.
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/scrollRestoration) and [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollrestoration) also say it's not compatible.
This can be tested in any site.

There is any other feature that enables this behaviour in this browser?

Answer (score 0):

> There is any other feature that enables this behaviour in this
>   browser?

Unfortunately, from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/scrollRestoration) and [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollrestoration), we can see that the scrollRestoration property doesn't support the legacy version of Microsoft Edge(Microsoft EdgeHTML 12 ~ 18) but it supports Edge 79+

So, as a workaround, I suggest you could upgrade the Microsoft Edge to the latest version, and install [the New Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge).